# Rename node name if selected node rename then skip self in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<TestCase name="TestCase1" UID="1" State="Checked" DataSourceId="1" order="1">    
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase name="TestCase2" order="2" UID="7c914deb-8f44-4f00-90db-2f36052611c5" State="Checked" DataSourceId="" />
<TestCase name="TestCase3" order="3" UID="7c914deb-8f44-4f00-90db-2f36052611c6" State="Checked" DataSourceId="" />
```

I tried to implement node name rename by changing its attribute value with below function but it's checking for self too.

```
private bool RenameTestCase(string oldValue, string newValue, string selectedNodeUID)
{
    bool IsSuccess = false;
    XmlNodeList nodeListToUpdate = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("TestCase");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeListToUpdate)
    {
        if (node.Attributes[CommonDef.NameTag] != null &&
            node.Attributes[CommonDef.ATTRIBUTE_UID] != null &&
            node.Attributes[CommonDef.ATTRIBUTE_UID].Value != selectedNodeUID &&
            node.Attributes[CommonDef.NameTag].Value == newValue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes[CommonDef.NameTag].Value + " is already exists.");
            IsSuccess = false;
        }
        else
        {
            node.Attributes[CommonDef.NameTag].Value = newValue;
            IsSuccess = true;
        }
    }
    xmlDocument.Save(Path.Combine(l_csConfigFolderPath, CommonDef.TESTSUITE_DATA));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Linq as you seem to have an [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) as your xml container I would suggest using the method [`SelectSingleNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx) that is available on that instance and allows for doing an XPath search. Your code would look like this:

```
private bool RenameTestCase(string oldValue, string newValue, string selectedNodeUID)
{
    if (selectedNodeUID == null) throw new ArgumentException("selectedNodeUID", "is null");
    if (newValue == null) throw new ArgumentException("newValue", "is null");

    bool IsSuccess = false;
    // check with Xpath
    // if the any nodes named TestCase : //TestCase[]
    // where its UID attribute isn't equal: not(@UID='{0}')
    // and the name attribute equals our newvalue: @name='{1}'
    var nodeExist = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(
        String.Format("//TestCase[not(@UID='{0}') and @name='{1}']", 
          selectedNodeUID,
          newValue));
    if (nodeExist != null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(newValue + " is already exists.");
        IsSuccess = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // find the node to update
        // any TestCase node: //TestCase[]
        // where the UID attribute equals the selectedUid: @UID='{0}'
        var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(
            String.Format("//TestCase[@UID='{0}']", selectedNodeUID)); 
        if (node == null) 
        {
           // error
           MessageBox.Show(selectedNodeUID + " UID not found");
           IsSuccess = false;
        } 
        else
        {
           // set the new value
           node.Attributes[CommonDef.NameTag].Value = newValue;
           IsSuccess = true;
        }
    }

    xmlDocument.Save(Path.Combine(l_csConfigFolderPath, CommonDef.TESTSUITE_DATA));

    // don't forget to return something
    return IsSuccess;
}
```

Notice that I added an return statement so your IsSuccess value gets returned to the caller. I'm not sure if intended but the `oldValue` parameter was and is never used. Consider removing it or add it as an extra check. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

If you're open to use XDocument instead this could be your solution:

```
private bool RenameTestCaseXdoc(string oldValue, string newValue, string selectedNodeUID)
{
    if (selectedNodeUID == null) throw new ArgumentException("selectedNodeUID", "is null");
    if (newValue == null) throw new ArgumentException("newValue", "is null");

    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(l_csConfigFolderPath, CommonDef.TESTSUITE_DATA));

    var exist = xdoc.Descendants("TestCase")
        .Where(elem => elem.Attribute("UID").Value != selectedNodeUID 
                    && elem.Attribute("name").Value == newValue)
        .Any();
    if (exist) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show(newValue + " is already exists.");
      return false;
    } 
    else
    {
       var element = xdoc.Descendants("TestCase")
                     .Where(elem => elem.Attribute("UID").Value == selectedNodeUID)
                     .SingleOrDefault();
        if (element == null) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectedNodeUID + " not found.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            element.Attribute("name").Value = newValue;
        }
    }
    xdoc.Save(Path.Combine(l_csConfigFolderPath, CommonDef.TESTSUITE_DATA));
    return true;
}
```